# Fk does not allow duplicate data in SQL Server (ASPNETZero)

Tags: database, asp.net-core

I am using AspNet zero framework code first approach,
i have two entities , parent **questionOption** and child entity **userAnswer** with Fk QuestionOptionId,
*UserAnswer does not allow duplicate QuestionOptionId even i dont create any index aur unique constrant on questionOptionId (i have mentioned picture).* 
It doesnot give any exception or any error query execute successfully but does not create new duplicate/new record

> what i have tried so far

- if i input data manually with insert query **SqlServe** allows me to
  insert duplicate questionOptionId buy ASPNet zero does not add/insert
  any duplicate QuestionOptionId,
- QuestionOptionId is not null field just for checking i made it nullable and tried to save duplicate record i creates new record but update previous record  questionOptionId with null

> here is my insertLink Query

```
 public async Task RCreateOrEdit(CreateOrEditUserAnswerDto input)
    {
var userAnswer = ObjectMapper.Map<UserAnswer>(input);
            if (AbpSession.TenantId != null)
            {
                userAnswer.TenantId = (int)AbpSession.TenantId;
            }

            await _userAnswerRepository.InsertAsync(userAnswer);
            await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
            input.Id = userAnswer.Id;
}
```

> this is what SQL SERVER created

[image]

> ChildModel

```
 public class UserAnswer : FullAuditedEntity<long>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }


    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual long QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string UserComment { get; set; }

    public virtual long SessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SessionId")]
    public Session SessionFk { get; set; }

    public virtual long QuestionOptionId { get; set; }
    public QuestionOption QuestionOptionFk { get; set; }

}
```

> Desired Result:
>   I want **UserAnswer** entity will allow me to add duplicate QuestionOptionFk

Comment: Donot post images of code , copy paste it so that we can debug it easily also refer to this [ask].

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth thank you for you suggestion, but whatelse do you need ? All i have this related , posted already,

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UserAnswer : FullAuditedEntity<long>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }


    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual long QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string UserComment { get; set; }

    public virtual long SessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SessionId")]
    public Session SessionFk { get; set; }

    public virtual long QuestionOptionId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptionFk { get; set; }

}
```

[Define relation using array of class instead of class according to Conventions of one to many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api#fully-defined-relationships)